# In .net what are the difference between Eventlog and ManagementObject for retriving logs from remote server?

Tags: .net, event-log

I have found out following two ways for getting Application Event log entries from remote server.

**1. Using EventLog object**

```
 string logType = "Application";
 EventLog ev = new EventLog(logType,"rspl200");

 EventLogEntryCollection evColl =  ev.Entries
```

**2. Using ManagementObjectSearcher object**

ConnectionOptions co = new ConnectionOptions();
co.Username = "testA";
co.Password = "testA";
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\" + "machineName"+ @"\root\cimv2", co);
scope.Connect();

SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery(@"select  * from Win32_NtLogEvent");
EnumerationOptions opt = new EnumerationOptions();
opt.BlockSize = 1000;

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new  ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query,opt))
   {

     foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
                {

                       // write down log entries
                       Console.Writeline(mo["EventCode"]);

                }

   }
```

I can easily get remote eventlog using method #1 (Using EventLog object) without any security access denied exception. But using method #2 (Using ManagementObjectSearcher object) i get access denied exception.

Actually I want remote event log (only application and also latest log not all application logs) to be displayed in treeview like below

```
 -  ServerName
   - Logs
     + Error
     + Information
     + Warning
```

Can anybody help me in this to find out best way from this or any other?

```
Also the main thing is that user who reads remote logs may be in different domain than server.
```

Thanks
Mitesh Patel

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old post...

I think your only problem with #2 is that your scope should be:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + "machineName"+ @"\root\cimv2", co);
```

You are missing the double backslash in yours.

One thing to be aware of using method #2 is that it's executing wmi queries so the wmi host process on the remote machine will get hammered. From what I've seen it runs at like %45 CPU usage till the wmi query completes.

I don't know how method #1 is implemented so can't say for sure on that.

If you're worried about performance I would stay away from the .Net event log API and use the win32 api(s):

pre-vista/2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363657(v=VS.85).aspx

post-vista/2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385785(v=VS.85).aspx